# How to skip controller actions in case of authorization is not succeed in ZF2

Tags: rest, controller, authorization, zend-framework2

I am implementing REST API on ZF2. Now I need to check authorization token on Module.php and return with error if authorization failed. But I did not know how to return response from Module.php.

I wrote code to check authorization in DISPATCH Event of onBootstrap. Now how to return error from Module.php without accessing controllers if authorization failed. As only `exit` function/call make possible to return without accessing controller. But In that case I did not getting any response. Using json_encode(array) is not look like a standard as I am already enabled ViewJsonStrategy and using JsonModel in controllers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169699/zend-framework-2-how-to-place-a-redirect-into-a-module-before-the-application/14170913#14170913

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shortcircuit the event by having your listener return a response, eg...

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    // attach dispatch listener 
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', function($e) {
        // do your auth checks...
        if (!$allowed) {
            // get response from event
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            // set status 403 (forbidden) 
            $response->setStatusCode(403);
            // shortcircuit by returning response
            return $response;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well this approach will work, But a issue still exists. I need to send error message, But all i can use `$response->setContent($data)`. Now that is passed as text/html. Even using application/json headers not works. So only way to send needed info is using json_encode the data like  `$response->setContent(json_encode($data))`. Now I am already enabled ViewJsonStrategy but still I need to add json_encode.

Comment: Well after more analyze I found, request still goes into controller so executing code there. Look like only response packet is set from Module.php. Otherwise all the scene still the same :(

Comment: After the closure try adding a third parameter of the value 100. If I understand it correctly it will cause the dispatch event to happen before the controller action. It may also be worth looking at the 'events' code here: http://www.mwop.net/blog/2012-07-30-the-new-init.html

Comment: Checking after lot of time, Yes it is working, (However now it will be a scenario to access controller object `$e->getTarget()` ).