# How to stop loop redirection in ZF2 Module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, redirect

What I am trying to do is to redirect onBootstrap inside a Module.php.
I have this code:

```
$response = $e->getResponse();
        $response->setHeaders( $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', 'google.com'));
        $response->setStatusCode($response::STATUS_CODE_301);
        $response->sendHeaders();
        exit;
```

This code returns redirect loop. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

EDITED:
this code appends google.com behind the baseroot. How can I redirect to different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Location header must contain either a valid URL or an absolute path. Your header line should be:

```
$response->setHeaders($response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', 'http://www.google.com'));
```

Also, you shouldn't really call `exit;` in a ZF application. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169699/zend-framework-2-how-to-place-a-redirect-into-a-module-before-the-application) for the correct way to end execution.